# NoSuchBeanDefinition with TaskScheduler in Spring

Tags: spring, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to schedule a task with Spring. This is my code:

```
@Service
public class MyWork implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        workToDo();
    }


    private void workToDo()  { /*do it*/}
}

@Service
public class MySchedulerInvoker {
    @Autowired
    private TaskScheduler scheduler;

    @Async
    public void executeTask() {
    scheduler.schedule(new MyWork(), new CronTrigger(
            "* 15 9-17 * * MON-FRI"));
}
```

When I run, I get the following error:

```
ava.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
[...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name     'mySchedulerInvoker ': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private     org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler com.infoone.siglo.GestoreNotificheCtr.scheduler; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type     [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as     autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: [...]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private     org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler com.infoone.siglo.GestoreNotificheCtr.scheduler; nested exception is     org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type     [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as     autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: [...]
```

What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `TaskScheduler` bean available in the same context as your `MySchedulerInvoker`. You'd need to show some configuration for someone to point out why.

Comment: Uhm... I forgot to add anything about schedulers in my config files.